# Correct Usage of React.Events in TypeScript 2.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have an app using React and TypeScript. I recently updated my type definitions to use the npm `@types` namespace to store them in my `node_modules` folder.

Previously when working with DOM Events a method signature like this satisfied the type definitions:

```
public updateValue(e: React.FormEvent): void {
```

Now However I get compiler errors:

```
(46,25): error TS2314: Generic type 'FormEvent<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

And after looking in the react type definitions folder it does indeed take in a generic:

```
interface FormEvent<T> extends SyntheticEvent<T> {
}
```

My question is basically what is the use case for this generic, how should it be used and what advantages does it add? I could simply change my method to:

```
public updateValue(e: React.FormEvent<any>): void {
```

And this would satisfy the type definition requirement. But what is the intended use case?

Comment: You said you're getting that definition from @types? That's surprising, considering that the [DefinitelyTyped react.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts#L304) doesn't have that definition as generic.

Comment: @types is pulling from `types 2.0` - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/react/index.d.ts Not sure if I can aim it at a different repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the react.d.ts file you've linked, it looks like that generic parameter corresponds to the HTMLElement specified in the [currentTarget](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/react/index.d.ts#L276) property. The [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) would indicate this is typically an Element.

```
[currentTarget: EventTarget & T;]
```

T remains unspecified up to

```
interface ReactHTMLElement<T extends HTMLElement> extends DOMElement<HTMLAttributes<T>, T> {
```

which seems to support the idea that T is an element. I believe the goal of the generic is being able to access element-specific properties (src tags and such using `HTMLImageElement`, for example) on the currentTarget property. There's [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/299) that suggests doing something similar in the core lib.d.ts along with some discussions on issues involved.

From what I can tell the react typing is an implementation of that same core idea.